# Why can't my Spring application find they keys in my application.yml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've a Spring Web application that I'm writing, and I'm attempting to implement a middleware to handle authentication using JWTs. I've set up a configuration component to pull the configuration from my application.yml file to be used in the middleware, but it's pulling only nulls and 0s. I've tried multiple different configurations to get this, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, since the application is correctly pulling the spring configuration from the application.yml file.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Prehandle
2021-04-17 15:08:44.060 ERROR 14132 --- [nio-3001-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "s" is null] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "s" is null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.equalsIgnoreCase(ByteChunk.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.equalsIgnoreCase(MessageBytes.java:334) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.getValue(MimeHeaders.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.getHeader(MimeHeaders.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.getHeader(Request.java:398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getHeader(Request.java:2258) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getHeader(RequestFacade.java:690) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at com.cbp.my.middleware.JWTMiddleware.preHandle(JWTMiddleware.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:151) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1035) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

Prehandle
2021-04-17 15:08:45.949 ERROR 14132 --- [nio-3001-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "s" is null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.equalsIgnoreCase(ByteChunk.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.equalsIgnoreCase(MessageBytes.java:334) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.getValue(MimeHeaders.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.getHeader(MimeHeaders.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.getHeader(Request.java:398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getHeader(Request.java:2258) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getHeader(RequestFacade.java:690) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:88) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at com.cbp.my.middleware.JWTMiddleware.preHandle(JWTMiddleware.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:151) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1035) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:352) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

2021-04-17 15:08:45.950 ERROR 14132 --- [nio-3001-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "s" is null
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:352) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "s" is null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.equalsIgnoreCase(ByteChunk.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.equalsIgnoreCase(MessageBytes.java:334) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.getValue(MimeHeaders.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.getHeader(MimeHeaders.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.getHeader(Request.java:398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getHeader(Request.java:2258) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getHeader(RequestFacade.java:690) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:88) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at com.cbp.my.middleware.JWTMiddleware.preHandle(JWTMiddleware.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:151) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1035) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Here are what I think are the relevant files:

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cbp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myapp</name>
    <description>My API</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.yml

```yaml
server:
  port: 3001

spring:
  application:
    name: my-api

  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    initialization-mode: NEVER
    password: ${MY_DB_PASSWORD}
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${MY_DB_URL}:5432/${MY_DB_NAME:bagofholding}
    username: ${MY_DB_USERNAME}

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema: ${MY_DB_SCHEMA:dev}
    show-sql: false

jwt:
  secret: ${MY_JWT_SECRET}
  expiration: 900_000
  prefix: Bearer
  header: Authorization
```

JWTSettings.java

```java
package com.cbp.my.configuration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JWTSettings {

  @Value("${jwt.secret}")
  private String secret;

  @Value("${jwt.expiration:900_000}")
  private long expiration; // 15 mins

  @Value("${jwt.prefix:Bearer}")
  private String prefix;

  @Value("${jwt.header:Authorization}")
  private String header;

  public static final List<String> PATHS = new ArrayList<>();

  static {
    PATHS.add("/auth/login");
    PATHS.add("/auth/confirm");
    PATHS.add("/auth/recover");
    PATHS.add("/auth/email-check");
    PATHS.add("/auth/username-check");
    PATHS.add("/auth/questions");
    PATHS.add("/user/add");
  }

  // Getters and Setters

}
```

JWTMiddlewareConfiguration.java

```java
package com.cbp.my.configuration;

import com.cbp.my.middleware.JWTMiddleware;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class JWTMiddlewareConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    registry.addInterceptor(new JWTMiddleware()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns(JWTSettings.PATHS);
    WebMvcConfigurer.super.addInterceptors(registry);
  }
}
```

JWTMiddleware.java

```java
package com.cbp.my.middleware;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTVerificationException;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;
import com.cbp.my.configuration.JWTSettings;
import com.cbp.my.dtos.payloads.UserPayload;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

@Component
public class JWTMiddleware extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  @Autowired
  JWTSettings settings = new JWTSettings();

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Prehandle");
    try {
      String token = request.getHeader(settings.getHeader()); // Throws NPE
      if (token.startsWith(settings.getPrefix()))
        token = token.replace(settings.getPrefix(), "");

      Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC512(settings.getSecret());
      JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).withIssuer("auth0").build();
      DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);

      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      UserPayload user = mapper.readValue(jwt.getPayload(), UserPayload.class);

      request.setAttribute("decoded", user);
    } catch (JWTVerificationException e) {
      return false;
    }
    return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
  }

}
```

As it stands, removing the try/catch allows the app to correctly return the call, meaning that it IS pulling the datasource from the application.yml. Presumably, my annotations are incorrect, but I'm not sure how (especially since the debugger shows NULL for even the fields with defaults in the @Value).

I've also tried switching from @Values to @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "jwt"), '@Autowire'ing an Environment object, moving the @Values to the setters... Nothing seems to be working and I'm not sure where to look.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Middleware configuration you are creating a new instance of your JWTMiddleware, instead of using the spring managed bean. I am referring to

```java
registry.addInterceptor(new JWTMiddleware()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns(JWTSettings.PATHS);
```

Instead of creating a new instance of middleware, you should autowire the bean and use that instead. eg:

```java
@Configuration
public class JWTMiddlewareConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  
  @Autowire
  private  JWTMiddleware middleware;

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
   registry.addInterceptor(middleware).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns(JWTSettings.PATHS);
    WebMvcConfigurer.super.addInterceptors(registry);
  }
}
```

By the way, you also dont need the new operator with autowired bean

```
@Autowired
JWTSettings settings;
// JWTSettings settings = new JWTSettings();
```

Comment: Wow. The smallest thing. Thank you for that, it worked perfectly.